# Eigenvalue and eigenvectors of a matrix and its Hermitian conjugate

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $A$ is a square matrix, and $A^\dagger$ is the conjugate transpose of $A$. Let us assume $A$ has no nontrivial Jordan Block, i.e. $A$ is diagonalizable. Suppose $x_{\lambda, a}$ is the eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, i.e.
$$A\cdot x_{\lambda, a} = \lambda x_{\lambda, a}$$
Note that there can be multiple eigenvectors with the same eigenvalue $\lambda$, and we use the index $a$ to label them. 
Then $\lambda^*$ must be a eigenvalue of $A^\dagger$. I am wondering whether the following property holds:

> Any eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, i.e. $x_{\lambda, a}$,  can be expressed as a linear combination of the eigenvector of $A^\dagger$ with the eigenvalue $\lambda^*$. Concretely, denote $A^\dagger\cdot y_{\lambda^*, a} = \lambda^* y_{\lambda^*, a}$, then there exists some coefficients $t_{ab}$ such that
>   $$x_{\lambda, a}= \sum_{b} t_{ab} y_{\lambda^*, b}$$

Comment: I've no idea what "Here a is the index labeling the degenerate eigenvectors of λ sub-eigen space" means and what it has to do with the question about $\;\lambda^*\;$...

Comment: @DonAntonio I've added some extra details to explain your puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

No. Consider the matrix
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The only eigenvector of $A$ is $e_1$ (first standard basis vector). Now,
$$
A^* = \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix},
$$
whose only eigenvector is $e_2$. Even if $A$ is diagonalizable, this is false, as the simple example
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}
$$
shows.

Comment: But the example you mentioned $A$ is not diagonalizable. Maybe I need to restrict to the case where $A$ is diagonalizable. But thanks for the answer!

Comment: I edited.......